# How do I solve a maze using velocity and acceleration?

Tags: shortest-path

I need to solve a maze. I can move an object around in a 2D maze by giving it 1 acceleration in any 8 of its 8 directions.
The object starts at rest at 0 velocity.
By only adding an acceleration at each step, I need it to be able to solve the maze and finish at the end position with a final velocity of 0.
This maze is shaped with big open areas and not narrow corridors of tight corners.
It should also take the least amount of steps possible to get to its destination.

This as you can imagine, would look different than simply finding the shortest path.

Comment: What progress have you made on your own?  Can you identify a path to follow that would get you out of a maze?  If you had a path you wanted to follow, could you figure out how to issue accelerations to follow that path?  What part are you stuck on?  I'm not super eager to solve the entire exercise for you, but if you can show us your progress so far and ask a question about a specific aspect that might be more likely to get a useful response.

Comment: The version I have working can solve the maze using accelerations using A*, but I cannot figure out how to make it end at 0 acceleration. It speeds the fastest it can to the exit but does not slow down.
I solve the maze I would normally do using A*, but when visiting new nodes, instead of looking up, down, left, right, etc. I look at all possible nodes I can visit next by adding acceleration in any direction with my current velocity. I'm not even sure if this is guaranteed the best possible path, but from what I've seen, they were pretty optimal.

Answer (score 1):

At any point, the state of the system is a pair $(p,v)$ where $p$ is the current position and $v$ is the current velocity vector.  At any state, there are 8 possible actions (transitions out of that state, to another state).  Search over this state space using any algorithm for searching state spaces to find the lowest-cost path from the start state to the desired end state; for example, you could use BFS, A*, etc.  This should solve the problem in a clean, straightforward, and efficient way.

Comment: I use this to get the fastest possible path to the end. However, I'm stuck at the part of it ending with a velocity of 0.
Edit: Oh! I can have velocity of 0 as the end state in the (p,v) system. I see now.

Comment: @Popsucker, yes, exactly, that was what I had in mind.

Comment: Are you allowed to overshoot at the exit and return? If not, I suppose you are not allowed to run into walls, so you could just add walls around the exit point.